# Ajax call is sent only if debugger pauses

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following jquery Ajax call:

```
$.get("http://localhost/site/envoi.php", {nom: contactNom, email: contactEmail})
    .success(function(result2){
});
debugger;
```

If I look in the Chrome inspect element tool, I see the Ajax call is sent *only* if the debugger line is present and I stay on that line in debug for a while.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: I think your syntax is slightly wrong, what do you get if you use $.get(url,{nom: contactNom, email: contactEmail},function(result2){ alert(result2);
});

You're chaining a success function rather than using it as a callback

Comment: @TommyBs I believe his syntax is actually correct, from jQuery 1.5 onwards `.success()` `.complete()` and `.error()` are correct on a `$.get` function call to conform with the `$.ajax` functions. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jqxhr-object

Comment: Apologies, hadn't seen that before so my comment can be ignored.

Comment: chain also a .error( function(event, jqXHR) {}) and see if you manage to pick something up

Comment: @TommyBs to be honest I hadn't either, I just happened to come across it in the docs as I was making sure I had the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

It is an illusion, what do you do either side of this AJAX call? Do you have some sort of redirect call after the AJAX call?  It is probably more the fact that the AJAX call does not have enough time to return before the rest of your code is executed. If you need it to be synchronous then there are other methods of doing this, if you need the call to be asynchronous but only do something after the call is finished this should be done in the success handler.

**Actually I forgot there are .success handlers aswell to conform with the `ajax()` functions in jQuery so actually your syntax is fine.**

Comment: This Ajax call is triggered when a user submits a web form. After the Ajax call I do nothing. No redirect call after the Ajax. And yes, I reach the end of my javascript code before the Ajax returns, but still why would that stop the PHP script called from executing?

Comment: If the ajax call is triggered when the form is submitted are you cancelling the default action of the form?  If not then the page will redirect and your ajax call will be lost.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If not what is the continuing problem?